# how to do 3d matrix to 3d multiplication in python without loops?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, image-segmentation

I am doing segmentation part in my project, where I need to multiply a 3 dimensional mask to a color image.

What am doing now:

```
maskedFrame=np.zeros((rgbFrame.shape))
maskedHsvFrame=np.zeros((rgbFrame.shape))
for color in range(0,3):
    maskedFrame[:,:,color]=rgbFrame[:,:,color]*biscuitMask
    maskedHsvFrame[:,:,color]=hsvFrame[:,:,color]*biscuitMask
```

Is it possible to multiply without any loops in python?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, numpy can [braodcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) `biscuitMask` along the color dimension to fit the shape of the frame.
This broadcasting is done automatically. Thus,

```
maskedFrame = rgbFrame * biscuitMask
maskedHsvFrame = hsvFrame * biscuitMask
```

Should work without any loops or modifications.

PS,
If you are familiar with [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab), broadcasting is very much like applying [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun) only numpy does it automatically for you.